# MongoDB database listings different between mongos and replica set

Tags: mongodb, database

Please see below my query, I ran [show dbs] on mongos/router server and gives me 
different result than running the same command on Replica Set server:

As you can see below, some databases such as [clients] is in RS server but it is not in Mongos server, and vise-versa.. also some similar databases are different in size.. Why ?

I am migrating these databases to AWS, I am confused as to which database(s) I need to migrate ? and what about the size of some of these databases - for instance the DB [ **device1** ] is **0.156GB** when it is listed from RS server, but it is **0.078GB** when it is listed from RS server..

This is actually a production system and I am concerned if something is not right. Where should I check to get accurate information about the database I am migrating to AWS ? and how do I know which DB that is being used and the DB that is not used..

I am an Oracle DBA, I am new to Mongo, I'd appreciate all the advice & suggestions you can provide to get a clear picture about these databases before I can start the migration process.  It would also be helpful if I can find a detailed instructions as to how to migrate Replica Sets DBs to a new hardware such as AWS..

```
**>> From MongoS**
mongos> show dbs
admin                (empty)
config               0.063GB
dev-mgt              0.453GB
device1              0.156GB
rtime                0.203GB
zales                83.767GB
site                 0.953GB
eedb                 (empty)
test                 (empty)


**From RS server**
rs0:PRIMARY> show dbs
admin           (empty)
config          (empty)
Device1         0.078GB
clients         86.036GB    
rtime           0.203GB
zales           83.767GB
test            (empty)
```

Please advice. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all your collections are sharded. If you have a collection that isn't sharded, and you look for it on your secondary shard, you won't find it. Non-sharded collections will only go to a single replica set. You should always go through your mongos instance to browse your dbs and data.

From [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-shards/):

> **Primary Shard**
>
> Every database has a “primary” [1](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-shards/) shard that holds all the un-sharded
>   collections in that database.
>
> [image]

Comment: @Faris, you can click the check mark if it answers your question